# why gmail history list api return invalid ids?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I am doing the client sync job just as [the official guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync).

When doing the partial sync, why `history.list` api returns some ids that could not get from the `messages.get` api? The `messages.get` api would return

```
{
    errors: [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'notFound', message: 'Not Found' } ],
    code: 404,
    message: 'Not Found'
}
```

I get the same result on Google api explorer.

Comment: Can you report the email address and messageId that was returned from history.list that's returning 404 from messages.get() and I'll take a look?  http://goo.gl/NCpJXf

Comment: I got it. When fetching a email that is deleted permanently, gmail api would return this 404 directly, not some deleted notice.

Comment: Correct that is one likely situation (message was deleted permanently, not just moved to trash).  At some point it'd be nice if history.list() told you what change type it was (message add, message delete, label modification).  That would make it really clear without client having to do any type of inference.

Comment: @EricDeFriez I can't agree with you more.